# When writing in cursive, what is the proper way to write an acronym?

Tags: acronyms, style-manuals, handwriting

When writing in cursive, what is the proper way to write an acronym?

Would I just write the letters in cursive or switch to block text?

Comment: Obviously, it should be written as an [anachronym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anachronym). ;)

Comment: Write in cursive. Abbreviations in cursive are often written in capitals separated by dots: http://static1.bigstockphoto.com/thumbs/1/2/2/large1500/22101743.jpg

Comment: Switch to 'printing' (ie non-cursive) here. As with the address on a letter's envelope. Grice's maxim 'make things as clear as possible' (_manner_) is controlling.

Comment: There are various incredibly detailed books about how to write cursive, although it seems to be a dying art. [This from 1924 for example](https://archive.org/details/Masgrimes_Archive_Zanerian_Manual_1924). If you're being graded on it, do what your teacher says, otherwise nobody will read your cursive.